# One-to-many relationship not saved

Tags: nhibernate

I've got this relationship between a ReportRow (parent) and a Mark (child)

```
<class name="ReportRow">
    <bag name="Marks" cascade="save-update" inverse="true">
      <key column="ReportRowId"/>
      <one-to-many class="Mark"/>
    </bag>
</class>

// C# code
public virtual IList<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
```

But it's not being saved (in the Mark table, ReportRowId is always null).

I know these relationships always have to be bidirectional because of the NHibernate 'quirk' so for my Mark class I have:

```
<many-to-one name="ReportRow" class="ReportRow" column="ReportRowId" />

// C#
public virtual ReportRow ReportRow { get; set; }
```

I've even got some other examples of this kind of relationship working elsewhere in my project, but this one isn't working and I can't see any difference apart from...

... both Mark and ReportRow both have subclasses (e.g. ModuleMark and ModuleReportRow), which I'm using the joined-subclass strategy to implement the inheritance.

Would that have something to do with it? For both ends of the relationship, the mappings are defined in the parent class mapping rather than nested inside the `<joined-subclass>` mappings.

Thanks

Comment: Oh, it works if I save the row first (so it has an ID - session.Save(myRow)) then add the row to the mark (mark.Row = myrow) and save the mark (session.Save(mark)), and then add the mark to the row's collection (row.Marks.Add(mark)) and then save the row (again). Seems a bit convoluted though, am I doing it right?

Comment: There's this line in the docs: "Mapping one end of an association with inverse="true" doesn't affect the operation of cascades, both are different concepts!" From here: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional. Should I not expect cascading to work in this case for some reason? I don't understand why.

Comment: Sorry, the correct order is: save the row, add the row to the mark, save the mark. Which is simpler than what I said in my first comment. Still don't understand why I can't go the other way and just have it cascade down from the row to the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you adding Marks to the collection? Because the collection is the inverse side of the relationship, you need to set the reference to the parent object on the child when adding it to the collection. A common approach is to use methods in the parent object to maintain the relationship, e.g.:

```
   public void AddMark(Mark mark)
   {
      mark.ReportRow = this;
      Marks.Add(mark); // better yet map the collection as a private field
   }
```

I think of "inverse" as "who wears the pants in this relationship".

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I hadn't thought of doing it that way, but I think I will. And +1 for the pants comment, I like that (good way of remembering it!) :)